# Try Catch Block not preventing exception

Tags: c#, try-catch

I am building a program that will move a bunch of files.

```
            if (line.Contains("INSERT INTO BACKLOGITEM_ATTACHMENT VALUES"))
            {
                string AttachementID = line.Split(',', ')')[1];
                string FileName = AttachementsDictionary[AttachementID];
                string BacklogScrumID = BacklogLookupDictionary[AttachementID];
                BacklogItem Story = BacklogItemDictionary[BacklogScrumID];
                Product Product = ProductDictionary[Story.ProductScrumId];

                string FileToCopy = "\\\\dxScrum01v\\ScrumWorksPro\\scrumworks\\data\\attachments\\product" + Story.ProductScrumId + "\\attachement" + AttachementID;
                string FileToSave = "C:\\ScrumWorksAttachementExport\\" + Product.ProductName + "\\" + Product.StoryPrefix + "-" + Story.StoryTitle + "\\" + FileName;

                //Console.WriteLine(FileToCopy + " >>> " + FileToSave);
                try
                {
                    File.Copy(@FileToCopy, @FileToSave);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed: " + FileToSave);
                    throw;
                }

            }
```

The issue is that I am getting an exception when running the program. There are times when the file does not exist.

How can I make it so that if it fails it just outputs the failure  and keeps going?
[image]

Comment: remove throw and log/alert

Comment: `throw` inside a catch does not get caught by the outer catch, so it will still break inside the debugger.

Comment: While not a fail safe mechanism add a File.Exists before executing the copy

Comment: By the way, there is no reason to use the `@` in front of the variables, and you should be using it when you specify the file path (to avoid double backslashes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `throw;` if you dont want your application to break, you can handle the exception too